# How to evaluate size of file in Java before creating it?

Tags: java, file, size, inputstream

In my Java programm I need to create files and write in it something that i can get by Inputstream's read() method. How can I evaluate the size of file before creating it?

Comment: Why not use OutputStream's `write()` to write it?

Comment: Why do you need to know size of file?

Comment: You generally can't. Imagine the inputstream is connected to a network socket, or `/dev/urandom` - they're "infinite". Please clarify your use-case and your actual problem, your question isn't answerable as it is.

Comment: You can evaluate size by check how many(length of) characters that are going to write to file.

Comment: What difference would it make if you could? You can't pre-extend a file in Java. Your question remains obscure.

Comment: I have some storage limited by some byte size. Before creating file i need to know size of it, maybe i don't have enough space for it.

Comment: @alex.seluta: The usual way to handle that is to worry about running out of space when you run out of space, not beforehand.

Comment: So what information do you have available to you to predict the amount of data you're going to write to it? And why do you think you need to preallocate enough storage to hold it all in memory?

Comment: I have max size of my storage in byte and method saveFile(String str, InputStream input). I shoudn't save file if have not enough space.

Comment: Why not? You should be able to save any file a record at a time, or a line at a time, or a buffer at a time. Especially if you're just copying from an input. If you think you need the entire file in memory before you can write any of it you're almost certainly mistaken.

Comment: Ok, you are right. But what should I do? Writing byte by byte and each time check size of file? If i can't write something should I leave empty file?

Comment: Your question remains obscure. What is the input? What are you writing? When are you going to answer any of the questions you've been asked here?

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you don't *need* to know how big the file will be, but if you really do:

The only way you could do that would be to fully read the content from the `InputStream` into memory first, and then see how much you have.

You have several options for how to read it all into memory, one of which might be to write it to a [`ByteArrayOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html). (And then, of course, write that out to the file when you're ready.)

But again, the great thing about streams is that you don't *have* to read things all into memory; if you can avoid needing to know the size in advance, that would be best.

Also note that the space the file will occupy on disk won't be exactly the same as the file size; most file systems work in chunks (4k, 8k, 16k, 32k) and so a file that's (say) 12k on a file system using 8k chunks will actually occupy 16k of space.

Answer (score -2):

It's depend of the encoding used, but you can write it in memorystream and get the length.

Comment: What encoding? What memorystream?